# Django, 2 forms on one page, one form uses data from the other

Tags: python, django

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models

ATTACK_TYPES = ('EXA','Example')

class AttackImage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='attack_images')
    source_url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)


class AttackItem(models.Model):
    attack_image = models.ForeignKey(AttackImage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attack_used = models.CharField(max_length=55, choices=ATTACK_TYPES)
    hidden_data_found = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

I want a user to be able to create an attackitem and an attackimage at the same time, with the attackitem having a foreignkey relation to the attackimage, as you can see. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need separate forms?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. I need to create an AttackImage and an AttackItem in one request.